# Does shooting reveal other friendly positions?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Supposedly shooting "makes bushes invisible in 15m radius" (or so the help says). Does it mean, that if I, as a scout (lots of camo bonuses), sit hidden in a bush, then an ally drives right over and shoots at enemy I spotted, my position would be revealed to enemies, or can I sit safely next to a shooting heavy and wait as slugs fly over my head?

Comment: Where did you get the 50m radius figure?  The wiki's Battle Mechanics (http://bit.ly/17bNdf3) says its 15m.  Plus it's not all bushes that are effectively "invisible" after firing, all environmental camo in the 15m radius except the highest are invisible and the highest has its effectiveness reduced to 30% normal.  Unfortunately, I don't have a sure answer to your actual question.

Comment: It appears to me that your position would be revealed if an ally fires their gun within 15 meters of where you are hiding.

Comment: @Granger44: The video tutorial; I must have misheard "fifteen" for "fifty".

Comment: Given that they are tanks, even if you stay hidden the splash damage should still be a concern.

Comment: @Batophobia: If the heavy is right adjacent to me, yes. Very few weapons have 15m splash radius though.

Comment: I have had team mates roll out this urban legend, even attributing it to merely rotating my hull.  It comes from the enemy taking a tip from ["How Not To Be Seen"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhgCCqzui6A) and lobbing shots at likely sniper bushes even when no one has been spotted.  Or from artillery splash damage aimed at the spotted tank.  Or errant shots aimed at the spotted tank impacting nearby tanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Others shooting from bush does not reveal you tank sitting in the same bushes. The reason for bushes within 15m becoming "invisible" is to simulate gun flash when you shoot, making you lot easier to spot. As long as you dont shoot, the bushes will keep on camouflaging you, even if others are shooting near the same bush. This is quite easily testable with a tank with a commander with Sixth Sense perk.

Word of caution though, you can still get shot at even if they don't see you. Artillery  is still a big threat. As well as that, the shots that miss the visible team mate can hit you or, depending on your position, you can be in the line of fire and accidentally get shot at. In the worst case, your team mate can hide "behind" you on purpose and shoot using you as invisible cover against the enemy. I've had this happen to me a few times so I know...

Comment: Using heavies in the front line for meatshield as a tank destroyer is perfectly OK though.